# How can I resize the view background image?

Tags: ios, swift, view, image-resizing

I'm adding to background image in my view. But when I try to resize the image nothing happens. I know the image is too big, but I'm able to ScaleAspectFill:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "matchfield.jpg")!)
self.view.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

This code is not working. How can I do the resizing?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @jorjj Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to resize...

```
var image : UIImageView
image = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150))
image.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: following peace getting error because of " | " : `image.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth`

Comment: yeah, this works for UIImageView, but I'm working with view. How can I implement these codes for the view?

Comment: the question is about uicolor pattern, not uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

Considering Stanly's answer, try to put autoresizingMask stuff into square brackets and use commas instead:

```
var image : UIImageView
image = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150))
image.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth]
image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```